# How to clone RDD object [Pyspark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

1) How can I clone a RDD object to another?

2) or reading a csv file, I'm using pandas to read and then using sc.parallelize to convert list to RDD object. Is that okay or should I use some RDD method to directly read from csv?

3) I understand that I need to convert huge data to RDDs but do I also need to convert single int values into RDDs? If I just declare an int variable, will it be distributed across nodes?

Comment: Why exactly do you need pandas? If your data fits into a pandas Dataframe and you can fit it in memory on a single machine, I'm not sure if you need Spark

Comment: @cricket_007 The data I'm using now is a very small file. I need to scale my module and hence using spark. I'm a noob in RDDs so not sure how to work with them.

Comment: If you are using Spark2 (with the built-in csv reader) , then `Dataset` is the proper object class

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i'm using spark2, thanks i'll look into Dataset class

Comment: @cricket_007 how can I clone RDD? I was using rdd.distinct() but it messes up the index of values

Comment: I don't know what that means. You'll have to show a [mcve] of your code in the question itself. Other than that, you don't clone an RDD. You perform actions and "lazy"  transformation

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark-csv to reas a csv file in spark

Here is how you read in spark 2.X

```
spark.read
    .schema(my_schema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .csv("data.csv")
```

In Spark < 2.0

```
sqlContext
    .read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option(schema, my_schema)
    .load("data.csv"))
```

For more options as your requirement please refer [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

You can just assign a `RDD` or `dataframe` to another variable to get cloned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't that the scala syntax? And I don't think you answered the other question

Comment: How can I clone the RDD? I'm using rdd.distinct() but it's messing up the index of values

Comment: what do you mean by clone ? why do you need to do it ?

Comment: creating a new RDD with the current RDD. I'm using map to do this right now but not sure if that's the efficient way to do it

Comment: you can't just assign an RDD to a new namespace. That will be a shallow copy and both objects will have the same id, so if you modify one the other will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused on your 1) question. An RDD is an immutable object so you can load your data into one RDD and then you can define two different transformations based on your initial RDD. Each transformation will use the original RDD and generate new RDDs.

Something like this:

```
# load your CSV
loaded_csv_into_rdd = sc.textFile('data.csv').map(lambda x: x.split(','))
# You could even .cache or .persist the data

# Here two new RDDs will be created based on the data that you loaded
one_rdd = loaded_csv_into_rdd.<apply one transformation>
two_rdd = loaded_csv_into_rdd.<apply another transformation>
```

This is using the low level API, RDDs. It is probably better if you try to do with the DataFrame API (Dataset[Row]) as it can infer the schema and in general will be easier to use.

On 2) what you are looking for if you want to use RDDs is sc.textFile and then you apply a split by commas to generate lists that you can then manage.

On 3), in Spark you do not declare variables. You are working with functional programming so state is not something that you need to keep. You have accumulators which is a special case, but in general you are defining functions that are applied to the entire dataset, something that is called coarse grained transformations.